# UWP Binding not Working

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a Class "A" and Class "VisibilityStateProvider" Whenever any key of Class A changes at that time i call VisibilityStateProvider's NotifyVisibilityChanged but GetVisibilityValue(key) method never gets invoke . And Visibility does not get update on UI.

Thanks for the help in advance!!

```
     public class A:  IDictionary<string, object>, INotifyPropertyChanged

                {
                    public VisibilityStateProvider VisibilityProvider { get; set; }

                    public A()
                    {
                        VisibilityProvider = new VisibilityStateProvider(this);
                    }


                }
             public class VisibilityStateProvider : IPropertyStateProvider
                {
                    private A A;

                    public VisibilityStateProvider(A a)
                    {
                        A= a;
                    }
                 public bool this[string key]
                    {
                    get
                    {
                        return GetVisibilityValue(key);
                    }
                }
           private bool GetVisibilityValue(string key)
                  {
                     //returns true or false on basis of some condition.
                   }
         public void NotifyVisibilityChanged(string key)
            {
                var a= $"Item[{key}]";

                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(a));
            }
            }
             public interface IPropertyStateProvider : INotifyPropertyChanged
                {
                    bool this[string key] { get;}
                }


            //xaml
            <TextBox Text="{Binding A[mf_number1], Mode=TwoWay}" Visibility="{Binding A.VisibilityProvider[mf_number1],Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" ></TextBox >
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked your full code so here I will just share a thing that you need to know as a start. In your code the GetVisibilityValue(key) is never called because you haven't called it in the right way. Try the following code as a test:

```
 public A()
    {
        VisibilityProvider = new VisibilityStateProvider(this);
        var something = VisibilityProvider["test"];
    }
```

Here only if you are calling like the second line, then your below code can be called:

```
            get
                {
                    return GetVisibilityValue(key);
                }
```

Comment: Doing this way GetVisibilityValue Method gets called, but i want it to be called through the xaml  binding